# Error (private method `select' called for nil:NilClass):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Why would I be getting this error? How do I fix it?

> ActionView::Template::Error (private method `select' called for
>   nil:NilClass):

```
class MyformObject

  include ActiveModel::Model

  #validations


@form_structure =
  [
    {  name: :country, model: :car, field_type: :string },
    {  name: :street, model: :repair_center, field_type: :string }
  ]

  def get_model_from_name(name)
    model = @form_structure.select { |record| record[:name] == name }.first[:model]
  end  

  def type_for_attribute(name)
    get_model_from_name(name).to_s.capitalize.constantize.type_for_attribute
  end 

  def has_attribute?(name)
    get_model_from_name(name).to_s.capitalize.constantize.attributes.key?(name.to_s)
   end

def self.fields_of_model(model)
  form_structure.select { |record| record[:model] == model }.map { |record| record[:name] }
end

 end
```

#### UPDATED VERSION:

> ERROR: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass def
>   get_model_from_name(name)
>         model = self.class.form_structure.select { |record| record[:name] == name }.first[:model]
>       end

```
class MyformObject

  include ActiveModel::Model

  #validations


def self.form_structure 
  [
    {  name: :country, model: :car, field_type: :string },
    {  name: :street, model: :repair_center, field_type: :string }
  ]
end

  def get_model_from_name(name)
    model = self.class.form_structure.select { |record| record[:name] == name }.first[:model]
  end  

  def type_for_attribute(name)
    get_model_from_name(name).to_s.capitalize.constantize.type_for_attribute
  end 

  def has_attribute?(name)
    get_model_from_name(name).to_s.capitalize.constantize.attributes.key?(name.to_s)
   end

def self.fields_of_model(model)
  form_structure.select { |record| record[:model] == model }.map { |record| record[:name] }
end

def self.delegate_fields_to(*models)
      models.each do |model|
        fields_of_model(model).each do |attr|
          delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: model
        end
      end
    end

 end
```

Comment: Your `@form_structure` variable, as is now, is not accessible from your `MyFormObject` instance methods, that's why at the moment of calling it, it returns nil. If the content is always "constant", you can use a "constant", otherwise you can create a method returning that. Also there are other type of variables that can be accessed from any instance method, but their use isn't encouraged.

Comment: So you advice using a constant? What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this which make little easy to execute,

```
  def get_model_from_name(name)
    model = form_structure.select { |record| record[:name] == name }.first[:model]
  end

  def form_structure
    [
      {  name: :country, model: :car, field_type: :string },
      {  name: :street, model: :repair_center, field_type: :string }
    ]
  end
```

And for better encapsulation, you can put method `form_structure` in private scope.

Comment: I liked this, but get `undefined local variable or method form_structure  for  MyformObject` Not sure why

Comment: I could not get how it can throw error, as we have added `form_structure` method below it.

Comment: I defined it above, does that matter?

Comment: No, it does not matter. It should be included in class as instance method & work without such interruption.

Comment: What would be causing this?

Comment: I added a self.method. please look, that is the method throwing error. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to call it as `self.form_structure` instead of `self.class.form_structure`

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, a constant is a good way to handle that array, as is full of hardcoded values, and it contains just two elements.

So you can do something like:

```
class MyformObject
  FORM_STRUCTURE = [
    { name: :country, model: :car, field_type: :string },
    { nname: :street, model: :repair_center, field_type: :string }
  ].freeze
  private_constant :FORM_STRUCTURE

  def get_model_from_name(name)
    FORM_STRUCTURE.select { |record| record[:name] == name }.first[:name]
  end 
end

p MyformObject.new.get_model_from_name(:country)
# [:country]
```

There you can see that the constant can't be modified and is only being used within the MyformObject scope.

I deleted the model local variable assignment as it's not being used.

Comment: Any idea why ` has_attribute?(name)` gets a undefined method `attributes' error?

Comment: I need more information for trying to answer that question.

Comment: What do you need to know?

Comment: The whole error you're getting and the code involved.

Comment: If you have added `self` then try with `MyformObject.form_structure` when you call it from anywhere.

Comment: a went with a defined method, as it provided a little more flexibility and I have an inherited base, which I thought a method would be easier to overwrite, as needed.